# C# KeyPressEvents handled

Tags: c#, winforms, events

I'm using a textbox that I want to only allow numbers and I found that this statement works.

```
e.Handled = !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsControl(e.KeyChar);
```

But why is it !char.IsDigit() and not char.IsDigit()? Why is it negated? Shouldn't it be that if I enter a number, IsDigits returns true and that is what I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What this code is doing is saying if there is not a digit pressed and it is not a control character mark the event as handled so that further processing cannot occur.

So if a digit is pressed handled is set to false so the event passes on through and allows the normal processing logic of the keypress to occur.

As a clarification, see Edwin de Konning comments, setting Handled to True will prevent the keypresses from occuring as they mark the event as already handled.  This is why the operations are a not.

The statement is logically equivalent to:

```
e.Handled = !(char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) || !char.IsControl(e.KeyChar))
```

So if the character is either a digit or a control character (e.g. Ctrl+C) don't handle the event.

This is not good enough, however, to prevent non numeric characters from being entered, because cut and paste will still work.  As Edwin de Konnig suggested, you may want to look at MaskedEdit

Comment: Keypress will be ignored if Handled is set to true: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress.aspx

Comment: @Edwin de Konning: Thats what I said in the first paragraph and in the second I stated what happens if handled is false is the event passes on and allows normal logic to be processed?

Comment: I guess we both misread each others posts... will unvote it (you have to edit it first)

Comment: @Edwin de Konning: I've now edited it, with a clarification. Both of us now are explaining why it is a not on the handled however I agree with you that he should used a MaskedEdit as Cut/Copy and paste is not handled by the suggested code.

Answer (score 2):

It is actually !char.IsDigit() **And Also** !char.IsControl(). So it will ignore your input if the character is a digit **And Also** a control character. I am not sure if that is actually what you want (They even are mutually exclusive, as Bob Vale stated). Perhaps you should also look into the use of a [MaskedTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1fkc1cz6.aspx).

Comment: No, otherway round, his code will ignore characters that are not digits and are not control characters.  The e.handled of true prevents the normal logic processing from occuring

Comment: @Bob: I am quite sure E.Handled is only true when the char is Not a digit and at same time not a control char.

Comment: You are correct, however IsDigit and IsControl are mutually exclusive result sets so both can't be true at the same time.  It won't let me reverse my vote down, I miss read your statement as stating stating that e.Handled==false was the ignore condition. I'll flag and see if a moderator can reverse my vote

Comment: Definitely should use a masked edit, otherwise clipboard isn't correctly handled.

Answer (score 2):

When intercepting key presses setting `e.Handled` to `true` tells the framework that the event was already handled and it must not do anything on behalf of this key press. By marking all unwanted key presses as *handled*, you are effectively filtering these events, leaving only the keys you want to see.

Answer (score 1):

You should look what e.Handled doing...when you set it to true char wont be entered in texbox.

Answer (score 1):

Lets break this down.

Say we hit 1 on the keyboard, what exactly is happening.

- !char.IsDigit(1) == fasle so the whole will automatically be false, because when we use && if the first check is false then the whole statement becomes false.

Now if we look at `e.Handled` we see that if the value assign is false then we allow the value to be written to the `Textbox` where if the value was `true` then the value wouldn't be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

The above method helps in removing inputs made by using control keys like Shift, so that you avoid, cased alphabets and special symbols.

While you punch in numbers from the keyboard there is no control key pressed and so the resultant is false allowing the input of the number. (you cannot input a number with a control key)